# Why part of oldGen was collected after minor gc?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is my GC options:

```
 -Xms64G -Xmx64G -XX:NewSize=18G -XX:MaxNewSize=24G -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=1 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80
```

and logs:

```
109.127: [GC109.127: [ParNew: 20971520K->4194304K(20971520K), 0.9867550 secs] 32497068K->16761687K(62914560K), 0.9868580 secs] [Times: user=17.50 sys=0.33, real=0.99 secs]
114.982: [GC114.982: [ParNew: 20971520K->4194304K(20971520K), 1.0146370 secs] 33538903K->17802909K(62914560K), 1.0147240 secs] [Times: user=17.14 sys=0.32, real=1.01 secs]
120.811: [GC120.811: [ParNew: 20971520K->4194304K(20971520K), 1.0029230 secs] 34580125K->18848154K(62914560K), 1.0030200 secs] [Times: user=17.08 sys=0.31, real=1.00 secs]
```

Why the usage of oldGen is reduced after ParNew? is ParNew only used for young Gen?

My jvm is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is ParNew only used for young Gen?

You are right: ParNew only collects youngGen objects.

> Why the usage of oldGen is reduced after ParNew?

This is not the case.

**The numbers outside of the inner brackets are used for the total heap (young+old gen)**.

```
[GC109.127: [ParNew: YoungGenBefore->YoungGenAfter(TotalYoungGen), 0.9867550 secs] TotalHeapBefore->TotalHeapAfter(TotalHeap), 0.9868580 secs] [Times: user=17.50 sys=0.33, real=0.99 secs]
```

Actually some objects are moved from youngGen to oldGen in your scenario, meaning oldGen is actually growing (it is just a bit tricky to see on a first glance).

Lets take the first line as an example:

```
109.127: [GC109.127: [ParNew: 20971520K->4194304K(20971520K), 0.9867550 secs] 32497068K->16761687K(62914560K), 0.9868580 secs] [Times: user=17.50 sys=0.33, real=0.99 secs]
```

We see that 20971520K-4194304K=16777216K bytes were removed from youngGen. 
Removing this amount of bytes from the total used heap we get 32497068K-16777216K=15719852K.

But we can see that we still have 16761687K left in total heap, which is more than our calculated 15719852K.

This means that 16761687K-15719852K=1041835K were moved from youngGen to oldGen due to ParNew GC, thus still residing in total heap memory.

**References:**

Here is a good explanation for my calculations: [link](https://automation-performance.blogspot.nl/2012/02/understanding-concurrent-mark-sweep.html)

Here is some easy explanation about ParNew and oldGen and youngGen: [link](http://dasaradhreddy.blogspot.nl/2014/05/cassandra-tuning-jvm-for-read-heavy_1466.html)